# simplification in dafny, prove (a+b) / c == (a/c) + (b/c)

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to prove (a+b) / c == (a/c) + (b/c) in dafny.

I tried using a real for c, basically 1/c. dafny had trouble with real numbers though.

```
lemma s(a:nat, b:nat, d:nat)
    requires d>0
    ensures (a+b) / d == (a/d) + (b/d)
    {
        //Nothing in here works I tried using a calc == block, but I'm not really sure where to go with it because it really seems basic.
    }
```

I expected Dafny to automatically get this because it's quite basic but it doesn't seem to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The lemma is not true. Indeed, assuming it was true, Dafny would be able to prove false.

```
lemma no()
ensures false
{
    s(1,1,2);
}
```

Perhaps you want to work with real numbers instead of natural numbers?